# Coldfusion url variable

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a basic question here not been able to get it right....
I have a ColdFusion form abc.cfm and on submit posts to

```
<form name="MyForm" 
      method="post" 
      action="abc_action.cfm?vempnum=
                   <cfoutput>#qGetemplookup.emplid#&year=#form.year#</cfoutput>"
```

Now I have a textbox and a select box and I'm able to get the `emplid` value on the action page in the url but not able to get the year (which is the select box value)...not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In addition to the actual answers, I suggest that you make your url variables hidden form fields.  That way everything is in one scope.  This will simplify matters for you.

Comment: You might want to use cfparam to define a default value for your form variables, in case they don't exist yet: <cfparam name="form.year" default="" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to access `form.year` prior to actually submitting the form that the `year` input exists in. This won't work because the `form` scope will only be populated once the form has actually been submitted.

Trying to add `form.year` to the URL of the action is actually redundant, because when you do POST the form, the value selected for `year` will be available to you as part of the `form` struct.

Answer (score 2):

ColdFusion renders the action when the page is rendered to the screen. So, `#form.year#` is being populated with whatever it is set to when the page loads.

You're submitting via POST method, so `form.year` is automatically populated when the processing page (`abc_action.cfm`) receives the form submission.

Comment: glad to hear. make sure to accept an answer if it answered your questions.

Comment: @user747291 *form.year is automatically populated...* Just a quick note on that. In this case he is probably correct, because the form field is probably a type that still exists with a blank value like `<input type = "text">` or `<select>`, but not all form elements exist when the form is submitted if they contain no value. For example if no check boxes are checked, there will not be a form variable by that name so you should test with `structKeyExists()` or `isDefined()`.  Either is acceptable but `structKeyExists(form, 'yourFieldName')` is more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your form tag with `CFOUTPUT` and place the variable in there.

For example:

```
<cfoutput>
<form name="MyForm" method="post" action="abc_action.cfm?vempnum=#qGetemplookup.emplid#&year=#form.year#">
</form>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: A couple questions to rule out the obvious: 1) The form has already been posted, correct? I see you have `year=#form.year#`.  Was the from a a previous form?  2) It might be better if you pass the year variable as a hidden form value `<input type="hidden" name="year" value="year">`.